# Can a C++ class function tell whether the class member reference to an outside class has been updated since last call?

Tags: c++, c++11

Say I have two classes:

class A:

```
class A
{
    private:
        int _i; 
    public:
        A(int i){_i=i;}
        void update(int t){_i=t;}
        friend class B;
};
```

class B:

```
class B
{
    private:
        A &_a;
    public:
        void respond();
        B(A &); 
};

B::B(A & a)
:_a(a)
{}

void
B::respond()
{
    /*  
    if (a._i has been updated after last call of B::respond)
    {
        do something
    }
    else
    {
        do nothing
    }
    */
}
```

Is there anyway to achieve the task described in `B::respond()` in C++/C++11? What about `_i` is replaced by an pointer and `B::respond()` needs to respond to the content of a pointer?

Note that I can't modify class `A`.

Comment: Sounds like you are alluding to the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. Save the value of `a._i` in the `B::respond()` function and compare against that value in the next `B::respond()` call.
2. Set some internal flag when calling `A::update`. When calling `B::respond()`, check for that flag and unset it.

Comment: It is worth nothing that these two ways are not equivalent. The first one might suffer from what's known as *ABA problem*. Whether this is really a problem depends on the OP's interpretation of the term "update".

Comment: Actually, I don't think the first approach is a good idea. Because `a._i` might have been updated without its value being changed.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to directly see if a member has been accessed or updated, but there are indirect techniques. You could do something as simple as having a `bool _i_updated;` in class A. Then, inside of the A::update(int) function, simply set `_i_updated = true;` every single time the function is called. `B::respond` could check `if _a._i_updated {` and then set `_i_updated = false` every time it finds it to be true.

Answer (score 1):

You could keep the value of member variable `A::_i` as member of `class B`:

```
class B
{
    private:
        A &_a;
        int _i;
    public:
        void respond();
        B(A &); 
};

B::B(A & a)
:_a(a), _i(a.i)
{}
```

And consequently:

```
void
B::respond()
{
    if (_i != a._i) {
       // do something
    }
    else
    {
       // do nothing
    }
    _i = a._i;
}
```